# Post Request with clojure liberator

Tags: clojure, compojure, liberator

I am using clojure liberator to expose my services as REST service,I have a POST request, Below is the code, I could do the process on calling the service as POST, but I want to send back the event id as response of the POST, Can anyone help

```
(defresource send-event-resource
 :method-allowed? (request-method-in :post)
  :available-media-types ["text/plain"]
  :post! (fn [context]
           (workers/send-event context)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Raised an issue in liberator, got the response from there
https://github.com/clojure-liberator/liberator/issues/61

Answer (score 1):

Put the event id in to context map and look it up from handle-ok:

```
(defresource send-event-resource
  :method-allowed? (request-method-in :post)
  :available-media-types ["text/plain"]
  :post! (fn [context] {::event-id (workers/send-event context)})
  :handle-ok ::event-id)
```

The above code makes use of the fact that a clojure keyword is a function that when applied to the context map will look up "itself".